# How to sum values from a List of Double

Tags: list, help, sum

I'm in need of help figuring out how to add values present in a list of Double.

For example: `List<Double> doubleList = new List<Double>({1.5, 2.2, 3.4, 4.8});`

How do I add 1.5 + 2.2 + 3.4 + 4.8?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Double sum = 0.0;
for(Double value: doubleList) {
  sum += value;
}
```

Just loop through the values and add them together.

Comment: Thanks sooo much! You save me! ♥